# How to decode subject and date which were retrieved from gmail (Japan text)

Tags: php

I have a build a function using PHP IMAP to retrieve the email from G-mail. the function was going well every retreiving the message from gmail account but there was still a bit problem with decode subject and date in Japan language. Exactly for decoding in the message it worked. So I would like to ask you how can I decode subject to be readable with PHP.

Here is my function :

```
<?php
$hostname = '{********:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = '*********';
$password = '******';

$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to server: ' . imap_last_error());

$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

if($emails) {
    $output = '';
    rsort($emails);

    foreach($emails as $email_number) {
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $email_number);

        if(isset($structure->parts) && is_array($structure->parts) && isset($structure->parts[1])) {
            $part = $structure->parts[1];
            $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

            if($part->encoding == 3) {
                $message = imap_base64($message);
            } else if($part->encoding == 1) {
                $message = imap_8bit($message);
            } else {
                $message = imap_qprint($message);
            }
        }

        $output.= '<div class="toggle'.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
        $output.= '<span class="from">From: '.utf8_decode(imap_utf8($overview[0]->from)).'</span>';
        $output.= '<span class="date">on '.utf8_decode(imap_utf8($overview[0]->date)).'</span>';
        $output.= '<br /><span class="subject">Subject('.$part->encoding.'): '.utf8_decode(imap_utf8($overview[0]->subject)).'</span> ';
        $output.= '</div>';

        $output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div><hr />';
    }

    echo $output;
}

imap_close($inbox);
?>
```

and the result (not correct) :

[image]

Could anyone tell me which function in PHP can solve this problem.

Regards,

Comment: FYI, people in Japan don't use unicode and tend to use ISO-2022-JP (for emails). I don't know PHP well enough to give you the functions for that but it's normal that it's failing if you try to decode it as unicode.

Comment: thanks, let's me check  about  ISO-2022-JP in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public function encodeToUtf8($string) {
        mb_internal_encoding("utf-8");
        $str_japan = mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8", "ISO-2022-JP");
        //"=?iso-2022-jp?B?GyRCQjZCPjhsOEBCLDtuGyhCIC0gdGVzdGluZw==?=";
        return mb_decode_mimeheader($str_japan);
}
```

usage :

```
encodeToUtf8($overview[0]->date);
encodeToUtf8($overview[0]->subject);
```